# Magento login from custom made PHP site

Tags: php, magento

I have limited knowledge of Magento doing a POC for a project which is using Magneto for his store. The root website is in a custom made PHP site with no login.

Now I want to integrate a Login script though custom php site (root site) so when the user will hit the user id and password (from the root site's form) they will be login successfully and the Magento session will be created as like Magneto 's (i want to use "admin_user" table from Magento, a single login system) .

My question is I have to use the Magneto user name and password for this custom login php site. I am stocked with Magneto Password encryption.

**For More Clarification** : Suppose the site is under "htdocs/siteA" and Magento store is in "htdocs/siteA/store/"

So when a user in siteA and want to do login from siteA he will automatically loged in to Magento store siteB :)

My POC

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app("default");

Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));
$customer = Mage::  getModel("customer/customer");
$customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());

//login writes to $_SESSION
//login($username, $password);

$customer->loadByEmail('sashi@gmx.com');
$session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$x=$session->loginById($customer->getId());
$session->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customer);

if(isset($_SESSION['foo'])){
    echo"hi";
    $_SESSION['foo'] = "I'm in uo r session.";

} else {
     echo 'No foo yet; refresh!';
}
```

How to encrypt the User Password for Magento or any other way?

Comment: Magento uses MD5 Encryption try to encrypt your customer password MD5 and if you have still any doubt then let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Magneto Login form is posted to the customer controller, which locates at

```
MAGENTO_ROOT/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
```

First, we glance at the database data to get an intuitive view of the customers' "passwords": 66982d945e975796f1de141eb5848fde:3t(We use admin password in "admin_user" table as example). It looks like an MD5 hash, and it really an MD5 hash exactly, but with salt.

```
public function loginPostAction() {
    ....
    $session->login($login['username'], $login['password']);
    ....
}
```

The variable $session is an instance of the Session class for Customer Module. And within the login function, the authenticate function will be called. Finally, the answer to the problem can be found at Mage_Core_Model_Encryption class.

```
public function hash($data) {
    return md5($data);
}

public function validateHash($password, $hash) {
  $hashArr = explode(':', $hash);
  ....
  return $this->hash($hashArr[1] . $password) === $hashArr[0];
 ....
}
```

The COLON in the database is exactly the separator for hashed password and salt;